# How can I add individual filters to multiple power BI matrix coming from the same data source

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop, data-modeling

Hi I have a Dashboard with multiple matrixes in the same page, I need to set a different filter from the same column to each matrix, but I cant find a way to it, for some reason if I select each visual and I apply a filter, it applies to all of them, but I need to set a different one to each one, the matrixes are coming from the same datasource.

[image: 2 matrixes, one selected]

So I click on the matrix as show in the picture, and I filter that visual, lets say I click on "aardy" but it changes also the one to the left, I need one filter for each matrix and that it holds, for example, "aardy" on the one to the left and a filter of "tripprotectors" on the one to the right.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the visual on the toolbar and go to format - edit interactions.

[image]

Turn the cross filtering functionality off for each visual.

[image]